# New today widget added in XCode doesn't show up in Today

Tags: xcode, swift

I have added a today widget to my app (through the new->target->today widget). It adds the files and scheme, however when I run my app there is no today widget. I didn't touch any of the widget's code, just using the vanilla "Hello world" one.

I've once added a widget to that project, but then deleted it soon after. Could that be the problem?

Comment: No, I only tried removing the widget and adding a new one. As I stated in my answer, the problem was in mismatched deployment targets.

Answer (score 0):

Just as I posted this question, I found out I had somehow mismatched the deployment targets. One was 9.0 while the other one was 9.2. After fixing that, everything works as expected.